# Xamarin Firebase Database Connection to Listview

Tags: android, database, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

How can I connect my firebase database to my xamarin listview and get the value of it?

```cs
private List<string> mItems;
private ListView list_device;
private const string FirebaseURL = "https://abtrackslogin.firebaseio.com/";
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DeviceList);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(MainActivity.app);
    list_device = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_device);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(FirebaseURL).GetReference(auth.CurrentUser.Uid);
    GetData();
    list_device.ItemClick += listitemClick;
}
private void GetData()
{
    FirebaseDatabase
        .Instance
        .Reference
        .Child(auth.CurrentUser.Uid);
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
    list_device.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in your URL link https://abtrackslogin.firebaseio.com/.json/
It's Work for me!

Comment: it has an error Unhandled Exception:

Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: /.json. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']' occurred

Comment: Can you get the json data when you open the Url in browser? I used Jadson's URL,i could get the json data.

Comment: Here you usually try to debug your code and find the problem! and try  https://abtrackslogin.firebaseio.com/.json